# Can this be done only with c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have a list of orders like this:

```
OrderName      ProductBrand    ProductUnit

   A                B1              5
   B                B2              4
   B                B3              2
   A                B2              4
```

I'm interested in returning a Boolean value saying if there's an order which 
has both brands B1 and B2 , with product units greater than 3.

This is what I have have and tried:

```
public class Order
{
   public string OrderName { get; set; }
   public string ProductBrand { get; set; }
   public int ProductUnit { get; set; }

   public Order(string orderName, string productName, int productUnit)
   {
      OrderName = orderName;
      ProductBrand = productName;
      ProductUnit = productUnit;
   }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var Orders = new List<Order>
   {
     new Order("A" , "B1" , 5),
     new Order("B" , "B2" , 4),
     new Order("B" , "B3" , 2),
     new Order("A" , "B2" , 4)
    };

   var test = Orders.GroupBy(x => x.OrderName)                             
     .Any(y => y.Any( z => (z.ProductBrand == "B1" && z.ProductUnit > 3) 
         && (z.ProductBrand == "B2" && z.ProductUnit > 3)));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question. It is not very clear what you want to know.

Comment: You almost got it right: `Orders.GroupBy(x => x.OrderName).Any(y => y.Any(z => (z.ProductBrand == "B1" && z.ProductUnit > 3)) && y.Any(z => z.ProductBrand == "B2" && z.ProductUnit > 3));`. An item cannot be both (B1 and B2) at the same time, so you need to check twice.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen That's it . Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Orders = new List<Order>
        {
            new Order("A" , "B1" , 5),
            new Order("B" , "B2" , 4),
            new Order("B" , "B3" , 2),
            new Order("A" , "B2" , 4)
        };

        var test = Orders.GroupBy(x => x.OrderName)
                     .Any(y => y.Any( z => (z.ProductBrand == "B1" && z.ProductUnit > 3)) 
                       && y.Any( l => (l.ProductBrand == "B2" && l.ProductUnit > 3)));
    }
```

In your query you're checking for a single element containing both clauses, which is always false since an element can't have a `ProductBrand` `B1` and `B2` at the same time.

You need to check for 2 distinct elements, i.e. checking it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var orders = new List<Order>
    {
        new Order("A" , "B1" , 5),
        new Order("B" , "B2" , 4),
        new Order("B" , "B3" , 2),
        new Order("A" , "B2" , 4)
    };

  orders
    .Where(o => o.ProductUnit > 3 && (o.ProductBrand == "B1" || o.ProductBrand == "B2"))
    .GroupBy(o => o.OrderName)
    .Where(g => g.Select(o => o.OrderName).Distinct().Count() >= 2)
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .Any();
```

Comment: 1. OP asked for a `boolean` not the items themselves. 2. Your `ProductUnit` condition is wrong. Should be `> 3`. 3. Your logic is faulty. This will return a positive result if there are more than one of the same `ProductBrand` with `ProductUnit` of 3 or more in the same order. I.e you could have 2 `B1` and no `B2` and it would still return a match.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen You are wrong, I used Distonct on OrderName to prevent from what you are siggesting. For other remarks, see update

Comment: From what I saw first `Distinct` wasn't there. I might be mistaken though. After your corrections this answer is now valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution was almost there except that instead of checking that each order in the group had both a B1 and B2 brand, you needed to get all the B1 and B2 brands and check that you had two unique brands.

This is essentially the same as the solution above except with a slightly different expression.

```
var test = Orders
    .GroupBy(order => order.OrderName)
    .Any(group => group
        .Where(order => (order.ProductBrand == "B1" && order.ProductUnit > 3) || (order.ProductBrand == "B2" && order.ProductUnit > 3))
        .Select(order => order.ProductBrand)
        .Distinct()
        .Count() == 2);
```